# Given an array of (sanitized) attribute headers (metatags), how might I automatically create columns for each in my database based on those tags?

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, automation, rails-migrations

So here is the unformatted list (this one, an income statement, has over row headers like these, so yes, automation is the way to go here).

["Revenue", "Other Revenue, Total", "Total Revenue", "Cost of Revenue, Total"...]

Here is the list after I ran each array entity (string) through my simple little sanitizer program, `CleanZeeString.new.go(str)`.

["revenue", "other_revenue_total", "total_revenue", "cost_of_revenue_total"...]

So, I want to access Rails methods that will allow me to at least partially automate the database column creation process and migration, because this list has over 50 row headers, there are more lists, and I simply do not believe in doing things by hand anymore.

Answer (score 0):

LATER (personal progress):

- I'm starting to believe that a solution to this problem is going to involve getting outside of the rails "box" with regards to migrations. Yes, to solve this, I think we might have to think creatively about migrations...
- I know how easy this is to do either by hand, or with the assistance of some sort of third party scripting solution, but I simply refuse. I should have been able to do this automatically last night after a couple of drinks if I wanted to. Given the array, and the fact that each column is the same type ("decimal" in rails), this should be doable in an automatic, rails-like way.
- migration files are just normal ruby files. working on a solution based off that fact. time to get fancy. String#to_sym

Got it---

```
class CreateIncomeStatements < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    f = File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'lib', 'assets', 'is_list.json')) 
    is_ary = JSON.parse(f.read)
    create_table :income_statements do |t|
      is_ary.each do |k|
      eval("t.decimal k.to_sym")
      end
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I used the `eval()` method, and felt the ghost of my teacher slap me on the wrist, but, it worked. The key "ah hah" was re-considering the fact that migration files are just ruby files, and as such, I can just do whatever I want.

Comment: Solutions which do not rely on eval() are STRONGLY encouraged! If only for academic reasons (viz. out of curiosity)

Comment: Plus, eval() feels like cheating, too "loose"